# Set the value of a dynamically created dropdown list in JQuery (+ Flask)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, list

I have a Flask template (shouldn't be influencing this but just to be clear).
I create a correlated dropdown list :

One list with two choices : #select_bu
One list dynamically generated based on the first one.

Below the code :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    // jQuery selection for the 2 select boxes
    var dropdown = {
        bu: $('#select_bu'),
        book: $('#select_book')
    };

    {% if book == ""  %}
    var booki = "{{book|safe}}";
    {% else %}
    var booki ="COXL";
    {% endif %}

    // call to update on load
    updateBook(booki);

    // function to call XHR and update county dropdown
    function updateBook(booki)
        {
            var send = {bu: dropdown.bu.val()};
            dropdown.book.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            dropdown.book.empty();
            $.getJSON("{{ url_for('pick_book') }}", send, function(data) {
                                $(data).each(function(item,couple)
                                {
                                    dropdown.book.append('<option value=' + couple.book +'>'+couple.book + '</option>');
                                });
                                });
            dropdown.book.removeAttr('disabled');

 // this is where I want to set the value of the list :
            $("#select_book > option").each(function() {
                                console.log($(this).text());
                                if ($(this).text() == "COXL") {
                                $(this).prop("selected", true);
                                }
             });



        }

    dropdown.book.val(booki);

    // event listener to state dropdown change
    dropdown.bu.on('change', function() {
        updateBook(booki);
    });

});
</script>
```

To describe the code :

First I am setting up my variables.
Then the Flask code just check if there is already a variable passed through a form. This is a way for me to get back the latest selected value (from the POST in the python code I throw the variable back, not elegant but working... :-) )

The I call my function.

In order to populate my list, I use a .getJSON which work perfectly and populate my list correctly.

The issue is that whenever you change the value of the field and refresh the data (the list is in a form that creates a graph) I am loosing the selected field.

So I would like to set the list to the former selected data of the "book" list. 
I use several console.log and it seems that I cannot point to the list ... I have also tried several variation of dropdown.book.val("...") but same, even if no error it is not working.

If you have any hints about how I should proceed ? I guess i should try to point to the list but don't know how to do ...

Kind Regards,

Charles

Comment: Actually, just for info : console.log(dropdown.book.val()) return null....

Comment: Solved ... For information i have done it through the .getJSON loop using an "if" condition ...